# Cannot be resolved to a type - .java file is in package and isn't being seen

Tags: java, android, types

Here's the Griddler.java:

```
package com.pic2griddler.awesomeness;

public class Griddler
{
    public String id, status, name, diff, rate, info;

    Griddler()
    {

    }

    Griddler(String i, String s, String n, String d, String r, String in)
    {
        this.id = i;
        this.status = s;
        this.name = n;
        this.diff = d;
        this.rate = r;
        this.info = in;
    }

}
```

My screenshot isn't working on Linux, so I've taken a picture of it:  [image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10165371/IMG_20121211_140403.jpg]

As you can see, on the side (I think this may hint to the solution), it shows no down arrow on the Griddler.java file.

Some things of importance:

- I've read what's been recomended before (The Project->Source->Clean).
- I've followed many of the things outlined in similar questions, none has worked.
- I've restarted the computer.
- I've restarted Eclipse.
- I've deleted class files.
- I've taken the project out and imported it again.
- I haven't started a new project and just copied my files over (I would like a different solution, but if none comes up, I will do this as a last resort).

I'm sure this is an easy problem, but I honestly can't figure out how to solve it and don't want to use the work around I've been using.

Comment: did you import Griddler in your class ??

Comment: Paste the code causing the error, as well as the exact and complete error message.

Comment: It is all visible in the screenshot to solve, see my answer!

Comment: why is `Griddler.java` not expandable and not where it should be in aplphabetical order in the package explorer?

Comment: Jlordo:i thought that might have helped someone too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right clicking on the Griddler.java and selecting Build Path->Include.  I suspect you inadvertently excluded the file from your build.

Comment: Even though someone downvoted you, you were the most correct. This is what worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your screenshot you see the first quickfix available:

import Griddler

Just do that! (click on th efirst line: Import Griddler)

This will add an import statement where Griddler is imported
You also can do that manually:
In File UserGriddlers add one line

```
import com.pic2griddler.awesomeness.Griddler
```

in the import section.

Comment: I've done this and it didn't do anything at the top and I though this was because it was in the same package. I'll manually do this but I believe I've done it multiple times. Further, I let Eclipse make the file too and it did so so I put my code there, and same error.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Did you do an "import com.pic2griddler.awesomeness.*" in your Java client?

Q: Why aren't the "Griddler()" constructors both "public"?

Q: Are you sure "com.pic2griddler.awesomeness" is in your Eclipse Build path (yes, this generally happens automagically.  But please double check)?

Q: Could you post the exact error message?

PS:
You can always use "GIMP" to take a Linux screenshot:

- http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-ubuntu-linux

Comment: It's supposed to just be an object used I am the code. Not a separate java client. So both are or should be in the same package. I thought this grouped everything correctly. 

I'll make them public when in get in my room again and update. 

Yes it's in the build path, right about the auto generated files. 

I'll do so when I get in my room. 

I'll check out the tutorial too. When I normally take screen shots, with a program like shutter too, it is all black. Thanks!